# Chrome 67 does not shut down properly after reboot of 18.04

Tags: google-chrome

After every reboot of 18.04, google chrome 67 says it was not shut down properly.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: this has been asked again around any Chrome version on 18.04 with some extra information provided here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103495/want-chrome-close-normally-when-shutdown-or-reboot-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: answered in https://askubuntu.com/a/1108720/7143